# How to indent the text in a custom unordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pgf0ckfj/1/

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 45px;
}
ul li:before {
    content: "♦ ";
    color: #E55302;
}
```

As you can see the text is not indented like the normal `UL`.

How can I modify the CSS to ensure the text is indented for anything overflowing to the next line.

Comment: Do you mean like adding a `margin-left: -15px;` on the `:before`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `li` to `position: relative;` and then your pseudo element to `position: absolute;` along with a negative `left` value. Adding relative positioning will make sure that your absolute positioned pseudo element will position itself based on the location and size of the `li`.

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 45px;
}
ul li:before {
    content: "♦";
    color: #E55302;
    position: absolute;
    left: -15px;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>This is the first entry but only goes one line</li>
 <li>This is the second entry but only goes one line</li>
 <li>This is the third entry but it can go many many many lines and sometimes even a whole paragraph and I would like the text to be indented from the bullet.</li>
 <li>This is the fourth entry but only goes one line</li>
 <li>This is the third entry but it can go many many many lines and sometimes even a whole paragraph and I would like the text to be indented from the bullet.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `text-indent` attribute.

```css
ul {
  text-indent: -20px;
  /* add text-indent */
  list-style: none;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "♦ ";
  color: #E55302;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This is the first entry but only goes one line</li>
  <li>This is the second entry but only goes one line</li>
  <li>This is the third entry but it can go many many many lines and sometimes even a whole paragraph and I would like the text to be indented from the bullet.</li>
  <li>This is the fourth entry but only goes one line</li>
  <li>This is the third entry but it can go many many many lines and sometimes even a whole paragraph and I would like the text to be indented from the bullet.</li>
</ul>
```